# Is there a manual way to roll back an Update on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, automatic-updates

Long story short, windows 10 is utterly broken on my laptop after it automatically installed some updates. It's now stuck in a loop which always ends up saying "Undoing changes made to your computer"

I can't get into the BIOS.

I can't get into the Windows Recovery Environment.

Been talking to MS support for far too long so far, so I'm wondering if it's possible to add it as a secondary disk drive to another machine that does work, and manually remove any updates that were installed directly through the filesystem?

Comment: If you can't get into BIOS then that is something beyond a Windows 10 problem, because Windows should have nothing to do with that. Are you hitting the delete, F11, or whatever key you are supposed to hit at boot before the Windows spinning circle appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution MS were willing to offer was to format the whole drive and re-install windows.

When I moved the HDD into a working windows 7 machine it actually prompted a `chkdsk` to run over the disk.
It found a whole load of orphaned files, not sure if that was really the cause, but after backing up as many files as I had access to, I put the drive back into the other machine and now it boots.

tl;dr, `chkdsk` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in this loop last night
machine configuration : Dell Inspiron
windows 10 (original)

What the one thing you can do is to use an application name Dell usb recovery tool. You will have to format you whole computer be it ***c://*** or any other. You will need an extra hard drive to make a backup.
the process goes like this.
You will have to install the above application on other computer and open it and fill your service tag and make that pen drive bootable with that application.
Now plug in that pen drive to the laptop.
Go for troubleshoot.
Repair.
Install new original os.
It will ask for backup make a backup to other HDD.
Install and recover your backup.